# jQuery: Unable to access array elements using variable and array literal

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

first Q/ Noob.

I have several arrays set up inside `$(document).ready(function(){` 
--e.g.

```
var caribbean   = ["AG", "AI", "AN", "AW", "BB", "BL"];
```

Each element is a unique `<a id="X(2)">` inside a `<div class="flag">` 
Each element bordered with `<a class=9(3)...>` where class = a specific subcontinent

```
<div class="flag">  
    <a class="029" id="aw" href="#"><img class="media-object custom-media" src="flags/Aruba.png" alt="Aruba"> </a> 
    <p> Aruba </p>
</div>
```

--e.g. 029 = carribean

The user-selected subcontinent is verified in an array of all subcontents.

I hide all flags from all subcontinents.  No problem to there.

I'm trying to show the appropriate flags, based on the user selection.

Tried so far each(), forEach() -->  "TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a":jquery-2.1.4.min.js line 2000+

Found info on AJAX, PHP, and Json.

Now trying to 'for loop' through the array, "caribbean" (in this example).

Using alert I found that the contents of the variable arrayName ("caribbean") is being converted into a char array - arrayName.length === 9

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayName.length; i++) {
    alert( "Name: " + arrayName + "    " + "Index : " + i + "    " +     "Index value: " + arrayName [i]);
};
```

I have changed variables around in case of reserved words and have found quite a bit on creating the char array.

I am trying to reference the array without the contents of arrayName becoming it's own array.  At this point, I can't think of anything else to try and haven't found anything more pointing to a potential solution.

The project is HTML, CSS and javascript/ jQuery.  It uses the Bootstrap row/ column setup and custom overflow sliders.

Also, in looking around I'm not sure if I should be using hide()/ show() or display: block/ none.  I need the resulting display to sequence into the bootstrap column without leaving gaps, top down.  Please advise.

I would appreciate any direction you could provide.  I am stumped.  TIA.

RAd

Comment: Are you able to post all of your code here? I can see the problem you are having with your loop is that you are trying to iterate over the string `"caribbean"` rather than the array `var caribbean`

Comment: @DGS All of the arrays are having the same problems and set up as above.  The .flag elements are all set as above and I've yanked all array processing code except the alert.  It is called from another function.    `function addR5Flag(){
     $("#col5Display").attr('src', imageId);
     displayArrayFlags();
     }
     
    function displayArrayFlags(){
     //loop through the array and show each element by id

     for (var i = 0; i < arrayName.length; i++){
     alert( "Name: " + arrayName + "    " + "Index : " + i + "    " + "Index value: " + arrayName [i]);
      
      };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into changing your arrays into an object with the names as keys

`var arrays = {'caribbean' : ["AG", "AI", "AN", "AW", "BB", "BL"]}`

Which you can then call like so

`arrays[arrayName]` which will return the array you are expecting

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go!